# Magento 2 Don't show custom entity option "catalog_category" in magento import section

Tags: magento2

I am creating a custom module to import export categories in `Magento 2`. This module will use `cron` to import categories from a file. I don't want to show this option in `Magento` import process. This process will only run using `cron` and cannot be executed manually.

[image]

I don't want to show categories option showing in the above image. I tried removing label attribute from `import.xml` file but got an error

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="catalog_category" model="Plenty\Item\Model\Plugin\ImportExport\Import\Entity\Category" 
    behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>

Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid Document Element 'entity': The attribute 'label' is required but missing.
```

What should I do show that my entity option is not shown in `Magento` import section?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a simple jQuery string like following:

```
$j("#ID_HERE option[value='foo']").remove();
```

By using this, the only risk will be, that it can conflict, so call it something unique.

EDIT:

I understand the fact, that it will still be rendered in the first place, but to block it's rendering would require even more code, so as it's not done for security reason, you might consider a light solution.